# How do I read a .docx file in google colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, google-docs, file-read

Im trying to read a docx file into google collab since my main computer with anaconda is gone for maintenance. I'm trying to use the python-docx module, but to my knowlege I cant just pip install python-docx in google collab

'''

```
import docx

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

docxString = getText("week_8_document1.docx")
```

'''

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following; hope it works:

```
#Install python-docx
!pip install python-docx #<-- Yes you can directly install in Colab

#Import the tools
import docx
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload() #<-- Select the file you want to upload
file_name = '[whatever your file is called here].docx' #<-- Change filename to your file
doc = docx.Document(file_name)
```

Once you have the doc loaded, you can access texts by paragraphs or tables etc. Good luck boss